# solution verification algebra unique quadratic solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$y = 0$. For what range of $ x$, will there be a unique, strictly positive $r$?

$x > 0$

$0 = -3x + \frac{5}{(1+r)} + \frac{X}{(1+r)^2}$

let $p = 1+r $

using the quadratic equation:

$p = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }}{2 \times -3x}$

$1+r = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }}{-6x}$

$r = \frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }}{-6x} - 1 $

$\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }}{-6x} - 1 > 0 $

$\frac{-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }}{-6x}  > 1 $

$-5 \pm \sqrt{5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x) }   < -6x $

$\pm 5^2 - 4 \times (-3x) (x)  < -6x + 5 $

now what do I do with the plus and minus sign? or it doesnt matter? I can just square it both sides?

$0 < 12x(2x-5)$

so for this to be true

$x > \frac{5}{2}$?

But I was told that $x < 5/2$?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm too busy to write an answer. I hope someone can give a good explanation. Anyway, all we want is $x$ satisfying both $x>0$ and $\sqrt{25+12x^2}>6x−5$. You cannot square the both sides since the RHS is not always positive.

Comment: @mathlove All good! What if can we do instead if we cannot square both sides?